# Socket IO forbidden 403

Tags: websocket, socket.io, plesk

I have a simple socket.io app and it works just fine on local and also it's installed successfully on AWS server using plesk admin dashboard but when I connect to the app I always get forbidden `{"code":4,"message":"Forbidden"}` .. the entry point seems to work great http://messages.entermeme.com .. any idea what could be wrong with it ?

#### Frontend code

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const socket = io('https://messages.entermeme.com', {
  transports: ['polling'],
})

socket.emit('SUBSCRIBE')
```

#### Backend code

```
const cors = require('cors')
const app = require('express')()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)

server.listen(9000)

app.use(cors())

io.set('transports', [
  'polling'
])

io.origins([
  'http://localhost:8000',
  'https://entermeme.com',
])

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('SUBSCRIBE', () => {
    //
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

had a similar issue but when using nginx. So in case you still need some help:
In the end it turned out to be the URL I specified as socket origins. I didn't specify the port since the origin for me was also running on port 80 (443 for SSL) like in your example above:

```
io.origins([
  'http://localhost:8000',
  'https://entermeme.com',  // <--- No port specified
])
```

I updated my config and added the port. So for you it would be:

```
io.origins([
  'http://localhost:8000',
  'https://entermeme.com:80',  // <--- With port (or 443 for SSL)
])
```